# Where does Linux Mint mount an iPod touch?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, ipod, ipod-touch, linux-mint

When I connect an iPod Touch to Linux, it is automatically mounted and recognized. Rhythmbox is able to play music on it. However, I cannot find where in the filesystem it is mounted. I looked in /media and /mnt but it's not there. Where is it?

Answer (score 3):

In ~/.gvfs/iPhone

Since Ubuntu 10.04 and whatever version of GNOME shipped with it, access to the iPod is via GVFS over AFC using the very impressive [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/). GVFS puts its virtual file systems in the home folder in a .gvfs folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the iPod is mounted as an accessible disk but rather as a distinct USB device that uses its own protocol to stream music to a compatible program such as iTunes or in your case, Rhythmbox.